# DIV layout aligning div to the right using float or in-block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a few divs into this structure but nothing is working.

```
<div>
     <div>top</div>
     <div>middle
          <div>left</div> <div>right</div>
     </div>
     <div>bottom</div>
</div>
```

Ive tried using floats with abosolutes, blocks, etc closest im getting is with block-inline but the div which i need aligned right just sits up close to the left div,ived add text-align right with no joy.

Many Thanks
D

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle so we can see your CSS too?

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/zHscZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `left` and `right` div a `width` and let them `float`

Make sure you also clear the float by adding an extra div below with: `clear: both;`

Code:

```
<div id="wrap">
     <div id="top">top</div>
     <div id="mid">
         <div id="left">left</div>
         <div id="right">right</div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
     <div id="bot">bottom</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#wrap {
    width: 400px;
}

#top {

}

#mid {

}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#bot {

}
​
```

See code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/GZg6y/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div>
    <div>top</div>
    <div>
        <div style="float:left;">left</div>
        <div style="float:left;">right</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">bottom</div>
</div>
```

the bottom div with clear:both is probably not enough but does the trick in this particular example

google clearfix for this

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in different ways, one through float css property, make sure you specify the width as in this example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="top">top</div>
<div class="middle">
   <div class="left">left</div> <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
<div  class="bottom">bottom</div>
```

and your css should look like this:

```
.left{
float:left;
width:50%;
background:green;
}
.right{
float:right;
width:50%;
background:blue;
}
.bottom{
clear:both;
}​
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/M3met/1/